# How to add <%= current_user.name %> to 'Sign out' button in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and Bootstrap. I would like to have a 'Sign out, Mike' button. I tried the following, which doesn't work. I also tried it with .html_safe, however that didn't work either.

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out, <%= current_user.name %>', destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete', class: 'navbar-btn' %>
```

How could I display a button with the text 'Sign out, current_user.name'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out, #{current_user.name}", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'navbar-btn' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= link_to "Sign out, #{ current_user.name }", destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete', class: 'navbar-btn' %>
```

This way you can insert `name` in string